# Keras custom loss function that computes the slope

Tags: keras, loss

How do I write a custom loss function of keras that computes the slope of y_pred and y_true and calculates the difference between the two slopes?

Comment: y_pred and y_true are tensors of values, how exactly do you want to compute the slope? slope of what?

Comment: I guess he/she wants a regression function based on keras backend API

Comment: Correct, that is what I want FalconUA

Comment: You probably need to include more information about what exactly your network is doing (what are the inputs, what are the outputs it's trying to predict).